# Running Python script without the terminal appearing?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is it possible to run a piece of Python code (turtle graphics) without the python shell being launched?

Comment: Your OS is windows?

Comment: Yes, the OS window.

Comment: change your `script.py` to `script.pyw`